Pivot table showing a date field column as a number
In Excel, I have a pivot table that is showing a date field column as a number. When I hover on the value it shows the date. How can I format? I already tried formatting the field as a date.
The numbers are from a linked calendar. I would like to format them in short date format like 3-14. Any help is appreciated.

Have you tried to select the cells and right click and Format Cells...?

Yes. For the individual cells and row.

And what happened when you tried to format them as dates?

Sorry if I wasn't clear. No change. the pivot column heading still shows as a number.
